# "VBA Error 438 object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large Excel file where the data is retrieved from a database and exported to Excel where graphing is formed. The color of the different parts of the graph is controlled by a function in which you fill in a cell in another worksheet, and code reading of it. The problem is that the code will only work as long as there is one color, now I want to use my pattern, in this way, the Format Cells -> Fill -> Pattern style. I have tried to solve it in this way but i get Run-Time error 438 on the line with parentheses. All help are appreciated!

```
                Else
                   .FullSeriesCollection(i).ChartType = xlLineStacked
                   .FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.line.Weight = 2.5
                   .FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.line.ForeColor.rgb = _
                    getRGB(findInSub(setupLC, findInCategory(tables, _
                    Right(tbl.Name, Len(tbl.Name) - 3)).offset(0, 6), lineC, _
                    .SeriesCollection(i).Name))
                With Sheets("mysheet").Range("mycell")
             If .Cells.Interior.Pattern = -4142 Or .Cells.Interior.Pattern = 1 Then
             .FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.Patterned = .Interior.Color
             Else
              (.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.Patterned = .Cells.DisplayFormat.Interior.PatternColor)
             End If
            End With
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End With
```

/ Johan

Comment: Can't see a 'marked line' in your code :). Please specify which line is throwing the error

Comment: I didn't know how to mark the line so now it has parentheses around it instead. This one:
 (.FullSeriesCollection(i).Format.Fill.Patterned = .Cells.DisplayFormat.Interior.PatternColor)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem I can see: you are calling `.FullSeriesCollection` within a `With` block that is referring to a range whereas `.FullSeriesCollection` is not part of range object. It's part of a `Chart` object. You seem to have a few `With` blocks. I would suggest rather than using `With Sheets("mysheet").Range("mycell")` **WITH** block, just use the fully qualified reference to get to `.Cells` (i.e. `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("mysheet").Range("mycell").Cells ...`). This should resolve the problem if your `With` block before that is referring to a `Chart` object